# How to install elixir dev version on Mac

Tags: elixir

I use `brew install elixir`  to install elixir on Mac. It works for the released version which is `v1.5.2` at this moment. How can I install the dev version like `Elixir >= 1.6.0-dev` on Mac?

Comment: `brew install elixir --HEAD`?

Comment: Could you answer it so I can accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're already using Homebrew, the simplest way to install the latest dev version is to use `--HEAD`:

```
brew install elixir --HEAD
```

This will fetch the latest version from the git repo at https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir.git and make and install that. You can see exactly what it does by reading its recipe using `brew cat elixir`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use docker - you can mount your mix project into a docker container to run mix/iex. Here's a sample Dockerfile:

https://github.com/aabrook/elixir/blob/master/Dockerfile

```
FROM erlang:20
RUN git clone https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir.git
RUN cd elixir && make clean compile
ENV PATH=/elixir/bin:$PATH
CMD ["iex"]
```

2. Use a version manager such as [kiex](https://github.com/taylor/kiex)

`kiex install master`

Using kiex has the benefit of being able to jump to the source of std library functions when using the elixir-ls tool from vscode, see [this blog post](https://medium.com/@JakeBeckerCode/elixirls-0-2-better-builds-code-formatter-and-incremental-dialyzer-be70999ea3e7)